# Simple SSH Tunnel in Java that has firewall

Tags: java, ssh

I'm currently trying to create an automated test using Java that runs some commands in a remote server the problem is that this remote server has a firewall. Manually I can ssh into the first server (firewall) using putty. Then I enter the details to the Server I wish to execute the commands. I've seen some article with code that mention how to use java code (jsch.jar) that I can ssh into a remote client but I haven't found a good enough explanation when a firewall is present. Can someone give me an explanation of what I should be trying to do and with some code snippet if possible

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, just an idea.

`OpenSSH` has a feature called `ProxyCommand`. It allows one to automatically issue a command on a target system, presumably another `ssh`.

So I have several entries of this sort in my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host the.private.host.behind.firewall.net
  Hostname 10.0.100.106
  User username_on_the_private_host
  Compression yes
  ProxyCommand ssh the.firewall.net nc -q 1 %h %p
```

Now I can issue `ssh the.private.host.behind.firewall.net` and first get to the SSH authentication on `the.firewall.net`, and then to the second authentication on the target host.

Likely Java implements SSH protocol on its own, but perhaps you could create a construction like this one.